# Trying to find an easy way to recognize when a function is logarithmic based off of input values using math

Tags: function, math, logarithm

I recently found a video that explains how you can recognize linear, quadratic, and exponential functions from looking at their output represented in a table.

For example, the difference between y coordinates are equal as x scales consistently in linear functions, the ratio between y coordinates is equal as x scales consistently in exponential, and the second differences between y coordinates are equal in quadratic function.

I've been trying to find out through ingenuity and through Google, but **I can't tell how this pattern extends to logarithmic functions. What's the relationship between y coordinates as x scales consistently.**

I'm trying to figure this out for a program I'm trying to write.

Also, in case I haven't done a good enough job, [here](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=vLkOL-yqj60) is what I am referring to in the previous examples.

Comment: The rate between x and 2^y should be consistent, if I understand what you're asking.

Comment: I'm trying to find the relationship between y coordinates. The relationship between x and y will be specific to the logarithmic function, but there is a specific pattern that the y coordinates follow in all the examples. In a linear function (lets say y = 3x + 2), as x increments by one (a consistent rate) the difference between y coordinates is always 3.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.